# Using random forest for selecting variables returns the entire dataframe

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, random-forest, dimensionality-reduction

I am in the process of dimensionality reduction.  I am using Random Forest to find the columns with the highest
level of correlation with the target SalePrice column.

The problem is that the output is too large.  Definitely not what I want from it.  It is returning 259 columns.  Some of these
columns are a result of one-hot-encoding the categorical variables and adding them back into the dataframe,
which logically increases the dimension of the dataset.  However, I only wanted to return the columns
with the highest correlation to the target variable 'SalePrice'.  Not the whole damn dataframe.

Here is the output:

```
       0   1     2      3     4    5    6    ... 252 253 254 255 256 257 258
0        1  RL  65.0   8450  Pave  NaN  Reg  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
1        2  RL  80.0   9600  Pave  NaN  Reg  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
2        3  RL  68.0  11250  Pave  NaN  IR1  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
3        4  RL  60.0   9550  Pave  NaN  IR1  ...   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
4        5  RL  84.0  14260  Pave  NaN  IR1  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
...    ...  ..   ...    ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
1455  1456  RL  62.0   7917  Pave  NaN  Reg  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
1456  1457  RL  85.0  13175  Pave  NaN  Reg  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
1457  1458  RL  66.0   9042  Pave  NaN  Reg  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
1458  1459  RL  68.0   9717  Pave  NaN  Reg  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
1459  1460  RL  75.0   9937  Pave  NaN  Reg  ...   0   1   0   0   1   0   1

[1460 rows x 259 columns]
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/master/test.csv")

categorical_columns = ['MSSubClass', 'MSZoning', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'LotConfig', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1',
                       'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd',
                       'Foundation', 'Heating', 'Electrical', 'Functional', 'GarageType', 'PavedDrive', 'Fence',
                       'MiscFeature', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition', 'Street', 'CentralAir']

ranked_columns = ['Utilities', 'LandSlope', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure',
                  'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'HeatingQC', 'KitchenQual', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond',
                  'PoolQC', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond']

numerical_columns = ['LotArea', 'LotFrontage', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2',
                     'BsmtUnfSF','TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSf', 'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath',
                     'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath', 'Bedroom', 'Kitchen', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Fireplaces',
                     'GarageYrBlt', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF', 'EnclosedPorch',
                     '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'MiscVal', 'MoSold', 'YrSold']


def feature_encoding(df, categorical_list):

    # take one-hot encoding
    OHE_sdf = pd.get_dummies(df[categorical_list])

    # drop the old categorical column from original df
    df.drop(columns = categorical_list, inplace = True)

    # attach one-hot encoded columns to original dataframe
    df = pd.concat([df, OHE_sdf], axis = 1, ignore_index = True)

    # Integer Encoding
    df['Utilities'] = df['Utilities'].replace(['AllPub', 'NoSeWa'], [2, 1])  # Utilities
    df['ExterQual'] = df['ExterQual'].replace(['Ex', 'Gd', 'TA', 'Fa'], [4, 3, 2, 1])  # Exterior Quality
    df['LandSlope'] = df['LandSlope'].replace(['Gtl', 'Mod', 'Sev'], [3, 2, 1])  # Land Slope
    df['ExterCond'] = df['ExterCond'].replace(['Ex', 'Gd', 'TA', 'Fa', 'Po'], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0])  # Exterior Condition
    df['HeatingQC'] = df['HeatingQC'].replace(['Ex', 'Gd', 'TA', 'Fa', 'Po'], [4, 3, 2, 1, 0])  # Heating Quality and Condition
    df['KitchenQual'] = df['KitchenQual'].replace(['Ex', 'Gd', 'TA', 'Fa'], [3, 2, 1, 0])  # Kitchen Quality

    # Replacing the NA values of each column with XX to avoid pandas from listing them as NaN
    na_data = ['Alley', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'FireplaceQu',
               'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond', 'PoolQC', 'Fence', 'MiscFeature']

    for i in na_data:
        df[i] = df[i].fillna('XX')

    # Replaced the NaN values of LotFrontage and MasVnrArea with the mean of their column
    df['LotFrontage'] = df['LotFrontage'].fillna(df['LotFrontage'].mean())
    df['MasVnrArea'] = df['MasVnrArea'].fillna(df['MasVnrArea'].mean())

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, df['SalePrice'], test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

    sel = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100), threshold = 300 * "mean")
    sel.fit(x_train, y_train)
    sel.get_support()

    selected_feat = x_train.columns[sel.get_support()]

    return selected_feat


print(feature_encoding(train, categorical_columns))
```

The code for Random Forest is right after the train-test-split.

**Update**

After changing the code to the above version, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'Utilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Boston-Kaggle/Boston.py", line 66, in <module>
    print(feature_encoding(train, categorical_columns))
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Boston-Kaggle/Boston.py", line 37, in feature_encoding
    df['Utilities'] = df['Utilities'].replace(['AllPub', 'NoSeWa'], [2, 1])  # Utilities
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\security\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 129, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'Utilities'
```

Comment: Hi, I see you are working on the Kaggle House Prices. Just one question, did I get it right, that you want to get the correlation between the SalePrice and all columns? Wouldn't you just have to use `df.drop("SalePrice", axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.corr(df.SalePrice))` to get it (I mean after one-hot-encoding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need the for loop at all.

```
def feature_encoding(df, categorical_list):

    # One Hot Encoding the columns gathered in categorical_columns
    # take one-hot encoding
    OHE_sdf = pd.get_dummies(df[categorical_list])

     # drop the old categorical column from original df
    df.drop(columns=categorical_list, inplace = True)

     # attach one-hot encoded columns to original dataframe
     df = pd.concat([df, OHE_sdf], axis = 1, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Why did you remove the axis parameter?

Comment: There is no need for it if you specify what you are removing is columns, axis is then implied

Comment: Using `ignore_index=True` kills all the column names, and makes the rest of the cleaning steps fail.  (I checked; removing it works, but there are several categorical columns that aren't in OP's list and need to be accounted for.  And also filling with 'XX' fails since sklearn cannot work with strings.  @OnurOzbek, you'll need to fill with something else, presumably depending on the column type.)

Comment: Yea but now I'm getting a `KeyError` for my Utilities column.  I've posted the entire error above.

Comment: I don’t think the issue raised in your last comment has anything to do with the changes.  Check your sources and make sure that the column names match.  Also, you can encode ordinal values (I.e. ordered categories) by specifying the column type as ‘(categorical’)[https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html]

Comment: The name does match.  Just to be on the safe side, I copy/pasta the name from the dataset itself.  And why would one classify ordinal values as categorical?  Your link throws a 404 btw.

Comment: Ordinal is categorical just with a defined order.  Pandas see them as the same thing

Comment: Ah!  So you're suggesting that I should OHE them as well?

Comment: And what can I fill the `na_data` column with if not for a symbol like XX?  The column already comes with abbreviated values like "NF" and whatnot.  What difference would XX even make?

Comment: No need to OHE ordinal values.  Converting from a string to an integer is enough.

Comment: Instead of filling with XX you should fill with some integer value.  You can fill them with XX, but again somehow you have to convert XX (and all values in the column) to an integer of some type.  This can be done with categorical encoding or ordinal (if order matters).

Comment: Here’s the link to categorical in pandas.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html, either you need to OHE or convert to categorical / ordinal.  Though there are cases where you need both, for instance if a feature is represented by unique combinations of ordinal values, eg A and B , B and C and D, A and D.  In these cases it would be too cumbersome to come up with all possible combinations so using OHE turns each option into a boolean instead.

Comment: "No need to OHE ordinal values. Converting from a string to an integer is enough".  Yea but my ranked/ordinal columns were already encoded into integers earlier, which threw a `KeyError`

Comment: "Instead of filling with XX you should fill with some integer value" Yea but if one of my columns has a value like NA, which stands for "No alley", then how do I encode that with an integer when the rest of the column is also abbreviations of that sort?

Comment: ‘Key error’ has nothing to do with encoding.  You would only get that error if you are referring to indexes that are not in the dataframe (eg invalid column names).

Comment: Yea but my column `Alley` is totally in the dataframe.  I assume the problem comes from passing it back into the dataframe after re-encoding some of its values but I don't see why.

Comment: @OnurOzbek, I explained the KeyError above: `ignore_index` removes the column names.

Comment: Ah shoot.  I must've missed it.  Thanks, @BenReiniger

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem is in the for loop you have used

```py
for col in categorical_list:

        # take one-hot encoding
        OHE_sdf = pd.get_dummies(df[categorical_list])

        # drop the old categorical column from original df
        df.drop(col, axis = 1, inplace = True)

        # attach one-hot encoded columns to original dataframe
        df = pd.concat([df, OHE_sdf], axis = 1, ignore_index = True)

        return df
```

You have provided a return statement. This is the reason it is returning a dataframe when the function is called. So just remove the return statement in the for loop.

For getting the columns with the highest correlation to the target variable you can zip the lists of the features and the correlation values that you get and sort them in descending order with respect to the correlation values.

Comment: I don't think so!  If I don't return that df, the OHE columns are not added back into the dataframe.  I tried your approach and now its giving me a `KeyError` with the names of every column that was OHE.  Btw, that for loop is at the beginning of the function!  There is another return statement at the bottom of the function that totally overrides the first return statement.

Comment: @OnurOzbek, that's not how return statements work. The first one encountered will exit the function.

Comment: @OnurOzbek, as for the `KeyError`s, that's probably from the `fill_na` step. You don't have those columns anymore (and shouldn't need to fill them anyway) after using `get_dummies`. Finally, 300*mean might be too aggressive.

Comment: @BenReiniger That first one is indented within the for loop tho.  Why would it exit the function? (Not doubting you. Just confused).

Comment: @OnurOzbek have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/7129285/8043083 for better understanding

Comment: @OnurOzbek:  In particular, `return` is a feature only for functions.  For-loops (and other control structures) are unaffected (but have their own sorts of short-circuits, e.g. `break`, `continue`, `else`).  For-loops also don't have their own local variables, so in your code the dataframe changes persist past the loop, so just removing that `return` statement should do what you want.

Comment: @BenReiniger Now I'm getting `KeyError: 'Utilities'`.  It's basically not recognizing my Utilities column.  You can see that in the above code, I am integer-encoding its values because it is a ranked column.  This happened after I dropped the for loop completely.  You can see the update in the edits.